# How to create a suggester-query with spring-data-elasticsearch?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I would like to build a suggester-query like described here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-suggesters.html#search-suggesters

```
{
  "query" : {
    ...
  },
  "suggest" : {
    ...
  }
}
```

How can i do this with spring-data-elasticsearch? I couldn't find any setters for this kind of query within the NativeSearchQueryBuilder class.

I wouldn't like to use native json because it's uncomfortable while building complex queries using the builder pattern.

Comment: Using `ElasticsearchTemplate.suggest()` and passing in a `SuggestBuilder` you can create a suggest query.

Comment: @Val What if i need the suggest in combination with a query like it's described in the example of my question? I need to have a query in combination with a suggest on the same level.

Answer (score 3):

With short example - having following mapping on `sample` index and `test` type:

```
 "test": {
    "properties": {
        "description": {"type": "keyword"}
    }
}
```

and a document indexed:

```
{ "description": "blue sky"}
```

I would like to have a query:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "match": {
      "description": "blue sky"
    }
  },
  "suggest" : {
    "my-suggest-1" : {
      "text" : "blue sk",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "description"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in Java API you need to add bool query and a suggestion to `SearchRequestBuilder`:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery ("description", "blue sky"));

SuggestionBuilder suggestionBuilder = 
    new TermSuggestionBuilder("description").text("blue sk");                
SuggestBuilder suggestion = 
    new SuggestBuilder().addSuggestion("my-suggest-1", suggestionBuilder);

SearchRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareSearch("sample")
        .setTypes("test")
        .setQuery(boolQuery)
        .suggest(suggestion);

SearchResponse searchResponse;
try {
    searchResponse = builder.execute().get();

    for (SearchHit hit : searchResponse.getHits().getHits()) {
        LOG.info("Result: " + hit.getSourceAsString());
    }
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    LOG.error("Exception while executing query {}", e);
}
```

When you debug searchResponse object, it looks like this:

```
{
   "took":2,
    ...,
   "hits":{
      "total":1,
      "max_score":0.2876821,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_index":"sample",
            "_type":"test",
            "_id":"AV1b42zWa7i_qjvIODcL",
            "_score":0.2876821,
            "_source":{
               "description":"blue sky"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "suggest":{
      "my-suggest-1":[
         {
            "text":"blue sk",
            "offset":0,
            "length":7,
            "options":[
               {
                  "text":"blue sky",
                  "score":0.85714287,
                  "freq":1
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Would the SearchRequestBuilder typically be used inside a custom repository implementation?

Comment: Yes, typically any access to database/storage should be placed in Repository Layer. This allows to keep your Service Layer independent of underlying data store.